# TKinter: Changing BG color of label within loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to change a specific label's background color within a loop to simulate an animation of randomly selecting a box.

I know that I can define a function to change a label's color with a checkbox, but I am directly attempting to change it within a loop.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=3)

frame.grid()

x = 0
y = 0
start = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start").grid(column=0, row=0)
for name in results:
    inner_frame = tk.Frame(frame, bg = "black")
    # button = ttk.Button(inner_frame, text="Test").grid(column=0, row=0)
    label = ttk.Label(inner_frame, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", justify='center', anchor='center', text="test", width=3)).grid(column=0, row=1)
    inner_frame.grid(column=x, row=y)
    if (x == 2):
        x = 0
        y+=1
    else:
        x+=1

frame.pack(padx=0, pady=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example of the grid like label structure I'm going for. Can I place each label into a list and change the background color programmatically in this way?

Here's a (crude) drawing of what I would like to happen:

Iteration 1:
[image]

Iteration 2:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to simulate "animation" of selecting random Label by changing it's background color:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from random import choice


class GridApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Grid Application")
        self.labels = []
        self.current_label = None
        self.create_grid()
        self.root.after(500, self.animate)

    def create_grid(self):
        for i in range(16):
            for j in range(16):
                label = tk.Label(
                    self.root,
                    text="test",
                    borderwidth=1,
                    relief="solid",
                    width=5,
                    height=2,
                )
                label.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.labels.append(label)

    def animate(self):
        if self.current_label:
            self.current_label.configure(background="lightgrey")
        self.current_label = choice(self.labels)
        self.current_label.configure(background="yellow")
        self.root.after(1000, self.animate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GridApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This creates this app:

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what I had imagined in my mind, but it demonstrates the concepts that I will need to do the animation I seek! Thank you!

Comment: Is there something specific I need to do to get it to actually update or redraw? I have something very similar to this (only difference is a variable delay for calling after), but the window isn't being drawn and displayed until the last iteration of my animate function. @andrej

Comment: I tried root.update(), but that only seems to get the second to last frame and doesn't respect my millisecond argument for 'after